# Apache X-FRAME OPTIONS

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

i'm tried to enable X-FRAME only my spasific VH

on httpd-default.conf

i set the line:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

on my website that i need to enable X-FRAME from specific Source:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://sites.com"
```

my main idea it's to block by default X-FRAME

using apache 2.4

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem using `Header always append...` (sometimes doesn't works) so I changed to:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://sites.com"
```

and it works!

Only remember than Chrome doesn't have support for `ALLOW-FROM` so it will be ignored and always can pass.

PD: It´s recomended to avoid the use of `X-Frame-Options` and change to `Content Security Policy` using `frame-src: 'src' https://sites.com 'etc';`